# How to close primefaces light box when it is playing a video?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF with Primefaces components. When primefaces's light box playing video, it is not showing close button on top right corner. I don't want use Escape button or clicking outside of the light box. I just want to provide a button on that to close or I just want allow user to see that light box's close button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<p:lightBox id="myLightBoxId" widgetVar="myLightBoxWidgetVar" >
    <h:outputLink value="#">  
        <h:outputText value="SHOW"/>  
    </h:outputLink> 
    <f:facet name="inline">  
        <p:button value="HIDE" onclick="myLightBoxWidgetVar.hide();return false;" />
    </f:facet>  
</p:lightBox>
```

Comment: this is working for me in a clean and isolated enviroment (without third party css, js and other resources)